# Java FileChannel class without using Java stream class

Tags: java, nio

I want to do input/output from a file. My requirement is not to use any java stream classes.
I've done some research and most probably I will need to use a FileChannel.

However, how can I get a FileChannel object of a particular file without using the Java Stream classes?

Is it by using RandomAccessFile? By using RandomAccessFile class, do I fulfil the requirement of "not using any java stream classes"?

Comment: By "requirement" do you mean "homework" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to access a `FileChannel` without using either a `InputStream`, `OutputStream`, or a `RandomAccessFile`.

And `RandomAccessFile` implements `DataInput` and `DataOutput` which provides an interface for reading bytes from a binary stream. So I believe even `RandomAccessFile` is a kind of stream class.

**Edit:**

I really don't know with what context you are calling a class as a Stream class. `RandomAccessFile` can still be use in your case, as the reading and writing to stream is very much abstract to user. It shows how to read or write files in a non-sequentially manner.

In general, we classify IO stream into following categories..

- Byte Streams handle I/O of raw binary data.
- Character Streams handle I/O of character data, automatically
  handling translation to and from the local character set.
- Buffered Streams optimize input and output by reducing the number of
  calls to the native API.
- Scanning and Formatting allows a program to read and write formatted
  text.
- I/O from the Command Line describes the Standard Streams and the
  Console object.
- Data Streams handle binary I/O of primitive data type and String
  values.
- Object Streams handle binary I/O of objects.

However, `RandomAccessFile` doesn't belong to any of the above categories.It comes under I/O mechanism introduced in the JDK 7 release(NIO). It will come under Channel I/O and not Stream I/O. So, use `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: @Kadne is there a possible way to do I/O without using any stream class in java? I don't think the difficulty is up to using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JNI if streams are not allowed!